# How do you properly explain the torque speed curve of a DC motor under the effects of field weakening?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

As far as I understand, in order to use field weakening to achieve greater rotor speeds, one needs to drive the motor with maximal flux at the stator in order to reach the voltage-limit-line (Spannungsgrenze.) Once there we modify the stator flux by reducing the stator current, this causes the speed to increase since the stator flux is inveresly proportional to speed. As stator flux decreases we get an increase in speed at the cost of a decrease of torque since the motor torque is directly proportional to stator flux and thus inversely proportional speed under field Weakening. I think this is true assuming that the rotor current is kept constant.

My question is basically: Why do I always see in diagrams a constant torque over a range of speeds before applying field weakening, and then we see the 1/x behavior after applying field weakening?

Comment: Show the graphs; link the web sites please. We cannot know what you see unless you reveal it. Add details to the question please.

Answer (score 1):

You could weaken the field at low speed, but what would be the point? Field weakening is used to increase the speed when we can no longer increase the rotor voltage.

The graphs are therefore plotted to show the motor at its most efficient, no manufacturer would plot graphs to show their product as less efficient than it could be.

With the field at a constant max, and the rotor current limited to a max by heating, the torque will be roughly constant.

Why is a field-weakened motor less efficient than a strong field one? One nice physics trick is to investigate the bounds, and extrapolate down to zero field, when the motor simply won't be a motor any more, zero efficiency! A mechanistic explanation is that the stronger the field, the less current you need for the torque, so there's less I<sup>2</sup>R loss in the windings.

Comment: I thought that rotor current is limited by back emf. Field weakening reduces the magnetic field of the stator and reduces the back emf in the rotor. This now allows a higher current flow in the rotor and the motor spins faster.

Comment: @vini_i No. In an ideal motor, rotor current is whatever it has to become to match the torque required from the motor. Weakening the field reduces the back emf in the rotor for any given speed, so the rotor has to spin faster to match the input voltage with the back EMF, the current being whatever is required. A sudden field weakening would require a rapid motor acceleration to the new speed, which would need a lot of torque, so the current increases a lot during the acceleration to the new speed. it sounds a bit backwards, but that's the way electromagnetism is sometimes.